# "extraordinary class assignment"?

Tags: word-choice

We were given an assignment in an University program course which is not related to that course. Can I call the assignment as "extraordinary class assignment"?

Comment: Yes, but that would not tell why it was not ordinary

Comment: *Extra-curricular* would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could, but in this context, ***extraordinary*** more readily implies ***amazing, incredible, phenomenal, one-of-a-kind***, that sort of thing.

As one of the comments mentions, ***extra-curricular*** would work better. You could also use ***out-of-the-ordinary.***

Or, more in terms with what you're talking about—a totally separate assignment—it may be better served by a word like ***irregular***, ***off-topic*** or ***unrelated***.